# Symfony2 - secure everything

Tags: symfony, authentication, configuration, redirect

I write an application in which I need to have everything (except login page) secured and redirect to login. I tried solution from http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html (Avoid Common Pitfalls -> Be sure the login page isn't secure) but it does not help me - my requests still are being redirected to infinite loop.

Here is `firewalls` section of my security.yml file:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern:  ^/login$
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    .*
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_validation
            success_handler: authentication_handler
        remember_me:
            key:      "%secret%"
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path:     /
            domain:   ~ # Defaults to the current domain from $_SERVER
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDIT: Of course I want only logged in and fully authenticated users to have any access.

Comment: Where is your `access_control` section?

Comment: I have no `access_control` yet. It's empty.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to allow anonymous access to your check path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Into `security.yml`

```
firewalls:
  main:
   pattern: .*
   form_login:
     provider: fos_userbundle
     csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
     default_target_path: /index #everything you want to redirect after login to
     always_use_default_target_path: true
   logout:       true
   anonymous:    true
access_control:
  - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
  - { path: ^/.*, role: ROLE_USER } #is just a role example, change it
```

This will do the trick

You miss the second part (`access_control` one) that will fire a `firewall` event catched by this firewall (in that case `main`)

Comment: It almost did the trick, but colliding patterns `^/.*` and `^/login$` still made me jump into infinite loop - changing `^/.*` to `^((?!login).)*$` solved my problem.

Comment: @KamilSołtysik: this tells you that you're doing something wrong. This configuration works perfectly for me (just tested now)

Comment: @KamilSołtysik: could you attach your security.yml? From start to end. This because what you're doing tells you that something is wrong, and this could cause you future problems

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6Hhhn7EM it's here. I have problem now, because user with ROLE_USER only can enter links starting with /admin

Comment: @KamilSołtysik: are you sure you'd followed my answer? I'd tried it against my application, against an example and against friend application, and do what you want